# ReadOnlyLongWrapper cannot be converted to ObservableValue<CAP#1> where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable

Tags: java, android, javafx

I creating JavaFX application. I create interface where user can set columns in TableView. This is working nice for me in PC. I today tried compile this using javafxports for android. On compile i getting error

```
ReadOnlyLongWrapper cannot be converted to ObservableValue<CAP#1> where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable
```

on line

```
id.setCellValueFactory(e -> new ReadOnlyLongWrapper(((ProductPS) e.getValue()).getId()));
```

Full code of my override interface

```
@Override   
public <T> List<TableColumn<T, ?>> setColums() {
                    List<TableColumn<T, ?>> columns = new ArrayList<>();
            TableColumn<T, ?> id = new TableColumn<>();
            id.setText("id");
            id.setEditable(true);
            id.setSortable(true);
            id.setResizable(true);
            id.setCellValueFactory(e -> new ReadOnlyLongWrapper(((ProductPS) e.getValue()).getId()));
            TableColumn<T, ?> name = new TableColumn<>();
            name.setText("name");
            name.setEditable(true);
            name.setSortable(true);
            name.setResizable(true);
            name.setCellValueFactory(e -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(((ProductPS) e.getValue()).getLang().get(0).getName()));
            columns.add(id);
            columns.add(name); 
        return columns;
    }
```

Some one now why on android is problem this lines? This is possible to change code and compile to android? My classes don't have SimpleProperty.

Answer (score 0):

The use of generics is in your case not necessary. Your `T` always gets casted to `ProductPS` and the value of the `TableColumn`s is known. This should do the trick:

```
@Override   
public List<TableColumn<ProductPS, ?>> setColumns() {
    List<TableColumn<ProductPS, ?>> columns = new ArrayList<>();
    TableColumn<ProductPS, Long> id = new TableColumn<>();
    id.setText("id");
    id.setEditable(true);
    id.setSortable(true);
    id.setResizable(true);
    id.setCellValueFactory(e -> new ReadOnlyLongWrapper(e.getValue().getId()));

    TableColumn<ProductPS, String> name = new TableColumn<>();
    name.setText("name");
    name.setEditable(true);
    name.setSortable(true);
    name.setResizable(true);
    name.setCellValueFactory(e -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(e.getValue().getLang().get(0).getName()));

    columns.add(id);
    columns.add(name); 
    return columns;
}
```